# Image on image Segmented

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey people I have problem with my game I created,
[image]

now that happen because the snake is List so I first initialize the head then the apple.
and every time I take the apple I get 1 more body's block
but because the apple was initialize before, so if I goes close to the apple ,
the apple is front than the body
what I can do here???

lol thank for aprove the pic